# how to fix bug in my site

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-5

So I'm experieincing a wierd anchor element being generated and I can't get rid of it. It looks as if there is a :before and :after element randomly being generated some how but Im not sure by what. The code seems fine:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
       <h1>Social Science</h1>
<!--       Algebra 1 Common Core Semester 1-->

        <dl class="accordion accorborder" data-accordion="">
        <dd class="accordion-navigation">
            <a href="#p1">World History Since Renaissance Sem 1</a>
            <div id="p1" class="content">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="small-6 columns">
                        <h6>Code:</h6>HS-ES-141
                        <h6>Offerings:</h6><span class="label">OFL</span><span class="label success">OFY</span><span class="label alert">PIE</span>
                   </div>
                   <div class="small-6 columns">

                       <h6>Course Materials:</h6> 
                       <ul>
                           <li>

                           </li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div> 
                <p>txt

                </p>
<!--                Panels-->
        <dl class="tabs" data-tab>
        <dd class="active"><a href="#p1a">Study Sheets</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#p1b">Study Sheets Answer Keys</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#p1c">Graded Assignments</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#p1d">Graded Assignment Answer Keys</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <div class="tabs-content">
        <div class="content active" id="p1a">
              <ul class="ss">
              <li><a 
              </ul>
        </div>
      </div>       
            </div>  
        </dd>
        </dl>

<!--        wh2-->

        <dl class="accordion accorborder" data-accordion="">
        <dd class="accordion-navigation">
            <a href="#p2">World History Since Renaissance Sem 2</a>
            <div id="p2" class="content">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="small-6 columns">
                        <h6>Code:</h6>HS-ES-142
                        <h6>Offerings:</h6><span class="label">OFL</span><span class="label success">OFY</span><span class="label alert">PIE</span>

                   </div>
                   <div class="small-6 columns">
```

I cut some code out but its the gist. For a closer look, please inspect element on http://new.omegadesignla.com/courses/socialScience.php to see the extra anchors showing up on the first 2 accordions. Thanks.

Comment: "<!--       Algebra 1 Common Core Semester 1-->

        <dl class="accordion accorborder" data-accordion="">
        <dd class="accordion-navigation">" close your dl and dd tags.

Comment: That's not a bug. You've defined several `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements in [`app.css`](http://new.omegadesignla.com/stylesheets/app.css). It looks like they mostly [redefine the box model](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) or [clear floats](http://davidwalsh.name/css-clear-fix).

Comment: ok. but why is it only on those 2? Also, the dl and dd are close at the very bottom i just didnt post the full code for the bottom. If you inspect element you can see that they are in fact closed. Also, if there are :before and :afters in the css why those only? How can i fix?